# How to create a map of demographics using Canada Census Data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, census, canada, demography

[image]

I understand this is an extremely vague question. I will start by telling you what I have:

- I have Canada census boundary shapefiles and want to map data by dissemination area
- I have Canada census .csv of populations and languages all organized by dissemination area
- I am trying to join the .csv and the dissemination area shapefile table so I can show my boss what's up
- I would like it to be organized kind of like what is shown here: https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/Single-Family/17597418/124-GADWALL-AV-BARRIE-Ontario-L4N8X3#v=de

Every time I try to make a query table it gives me this error - 000152 : Invalid input data. I have added new fields, tried changing the .csv, and now I am out of Ideas.

I got it from the StatCan website and I'm using ArcMap

Comment: Where did you download the data from, both the CSV and the shapefile? I recently helped my brother do this with QGIS and he's using it in Ottawa for Member of Parliament...

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of both your boundary shapefile attribute and CSV table?

Comment: In addition provide a screen shot of the tool box where you input your shapefile and CSV file to run the Make Query table.

Comment: I had to change the picture because I can't add more than one picture until I have 10 reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to join the csv to the boundary shapefile.

You should use a table join.

Add both datasets to ArcGIS.

Open the attribute table of the dissemination area.

Add a join with the csv based on a common field (dissemination area name maybe?).

If you want the join to be permanent, you'll need to export the joined layer to a new shapefile or feature class OR use the tool 'Join Field' to join specific fields from your CSV to your shapefile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I tried it that way already. I got a hold of someone who worked for a municipality and they told me I have to import the data from QGIS. It is a long process but I am slowly getting it. Thank you for your help